# Downcase BBCode Tag with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to covert a forum where BBCode tag are upcase. I need to write a parser to downcase my tag, from [QUOTE] to [quote], from [/QUOTE] to [/quote], etc etc.

I write this:

```
string.gsub(/#\[(.*?)\]/, ' \1'.downcase)
```

but of course it doesn't work!

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the match by using the block version of [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub).

```
 s.gsub(/\[(.+?)\]/) { |match| match.downcase }
```

or the more compact version

```
 s.gsub(/\[(.+?)\]/, &:downcase)
```

Also note there was a `#` that was preventing the regexp to match.

Example:

```
s = "from [QUOTE] to [quote], from [/QUOTE] to [/quote]"
s.gsub(/\[(.*?)\]/, &:downcase)
 => "from [quote] to [quote], from [/quote] to [/quote]"
```

Answer (score 3):

- Your `#` is wrong.
- You don't need to use capture (by putting `()`). You can refer to the entire match. `[`, `]`, `/` will remain as is by `downcase`, so no harm including them. In fact, your regex already possibly includes `/` in the capture, so it does not make sense to exclude just `[` and `]` from the capture.
- Your `'\1'.downcase` did not work because that is equivalent to `'\1'`. To perform a method on the match, you need a block.
- I assume your `.*?` in the regex intends to capture nested brackets correctly, but that works only half way. If you had `"[foo [bar] baz]"`, then by `\[(.*?)\]`, you can avoid matching `"[foo [bar] baz]"` and `"[bar] baz]"`, but it still mathces `"[foo [bar]"`. So `.*?` is not meaningful.

Considering the points above, you can do the following if you need to consider nested brackets:

```
string.gsub(/\[[^\[\]]+\]/, &:downcase)
```

Otherwise,

```
string.gsub(/\[.+\]/, &:downcase)
```

Comment: I am asking out of curiosity - why `*?` is needed? I am getting correct output with `*` only.

Comment: In case there is nested brackets.

Comment: I realized that `*?` did not make full sense. I edited the answer.